# I am trying to extract an element from the DOM, how is this done?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This code is ran each time it generates a graph, in addition it set the id of the tag for the graph using this. I have a case were I need a logarithmic graph. 
At first I thought it could be converted to a string, but this only returns [Object SVGSVGElement

[image]

Comment: At first I thought it could be converted to a string, but this only returns [Object SVGSVGElement]

Comment: Post your code, not a screenshot. Read the how to ask guide, and don't comment on your own post, instead update the question. Read about MVCE's while you're at it.

Comment: And update you question with more info instead of posting it as comments

Comment: What do you mean with "extract"?

Comment: I did it this way so the values of each var could be seen, thanks for oyur advice though.

Comment: extract....I want to take that element out of the DOM, and turn it into a string.

Comment: To remove it you can use `element.remove()` or `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)` for old browsers. Which string do you want to obtain?

Comment: Take a look at XMLSerializer

Comment: The question is difficult to understand. Can you provide more detail, especially about what you want to accomplish?  Are you trying to duplicate and modify an existing graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XMLSerializer) to convert a DOM object to a string

```
var s = new XMLSerializer();
var str = s.serializeToString(element);
```

Comment: this works, thank you very much!